# Seqkit - manipulate regex for parsing ID

Tags: regex, database, duplicates

I am trying to use `seqkit rmdup` to remove duplicated sequences from my protein fasta files. However, it's only the accession numbers which are duplicated and not the description or sequences. See example below.

```
Host_331002_c0_seq1 95 1381 2 + 
Host_331002_c0_seq1 1873 2112 1 +
```

So basically I want to set a flag which will stop at the first tab when searching the identifiers (stop after Host_331002_c0_seq1) otherwise I won't get any duplicates in my output file. This flag would fix it but I am not sure how to manipulate regex.

```
--id-regexp string                regular expression for parsing ID (default "^(\\S+)\\s?")
```

Could you assist with this issue?

I just started learning all the programming languages and I am not certain how to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Regex to match any zero or more characters up to the first tab excluding tab is

```
^[^\t]*
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/EBlC0x/1).